# Date in Milliseconds with getTime()

Tags: angularjs

I am looking to output dates in milliseconds but it is not working.

In the HTML file I have:

{{product.date_expiration}} : // which output ==> 2018-01-13T12:22:06.165Z

{{CurrentDate}} : // which output ==> "2017-02-10T13:18:58.339Z"

with:

```
date_expiration: {type: Date}
```

and :

```
{CurrentDate}}: {type: Date}
```

when I try to get dates in milliseconds:

{{product.date_expiration.getTime()}} ==> does not output anything

and:

```
{{CurrentDate.getTime()}} ==> output 1486733469830
```

Comment: date_expiration is probably a string, not a Date.

Comment: Is `{{produit.date_expiration.getTime()}}` a typo in the question, or is that typo the cause of the problem!?

Comment: sory , it was a typo, the post get edited

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `date_expiration` is not a date object.So `getTime()` function is not working on it.We have to use a filter which will convert it into Date object & give us time in milliseconds as we cannot use `Date()` in angular expression.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('inMilliseconds', function() {
    return function(x) {
              
        return new Date(x).getTime();
    };
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.date_expiration = "2018-01-13T12:22:06.165Z";
    $scope.currentDate = new Date();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
date_expiration: {{date_expiration | inMilliseconds }}
<br>
currentDate: {{currentDate.getTime() }}
</div>

<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```